# javascript += opacity of div isn't adding

Tags: javascript, opacity

```
function popupGrowStage3() {
if (popupContentContainer.style.opacity < 1) {
    popupContentContainer.style.opacity+= 0.01;
    setTimeout(popupGrowStage3, 1000 / 60);
    alert(popupContentContainer.style.opacity);
} else {
    isPopupShowing = 1;
}
}
popupGrowStage3();
```

the above code doesn't seem to add 0.01 to the opacity every time. the alerts just keep saying 0.01. why is it doing this?

```
popupContentContainer.style.width = popup.style.width;
    popupContentContainer.style.height = popup.style.height;
    popupContentContainer.style.backgroundColor = "#111111";
    popupContentContainer.style.opacity = 0;
    popup.appendChild(popupContentContainer);
```

this code is before that

Comment: is it just me or did the set interval post disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of `popupContentContainer.style.opacity` is string. So, when you do `+=` with a string, the result will be a concatenated string.

For Ex:

```
var a = '2';
a += 2; //results '22'
```

### Change:

```
popupContentContainer.style.opacity+= 0.01;
```

### To:

```
popupContentContainer.style.opacity = parseFloat(popupContentContainer.style.opacity) + 0.01;
```

Comment: yea this worked. why though? the alerts show numbers and i set the opacity with a number. does the div auto convert it to a string or something? is it because its a css style?